# VueJS - onclick to make active on new Array entry not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

https://codepen.io/donnieberry97/pen/GGKQRN

```
var demo = new Vue({
el: '#main',
data: {
services: [
  {
  name: 'Item 1',
  price: 200,
  active: true
},
{
  name: 'Item 2',
  price: 500,
  active: false
},
{
name: 'Item 3',
  price: 700,
  active: false
}
]
},
   methods: {

addItem: function() {
  var newItem= {
    name:this.name,
    price:this.price
  };
  this.services.push(newItem);
  this.name="";
  this.price="";
  toggleActive();
},

toggleActive: function(f) {
  f.active = !f.active;
},
total: function(){
  var total=0;
  this.services.forEach(function(f){
  if(f.active){
    total+=f.price;
            }
        });
return total;
}
}


});
```

When you use the input to add a new entry to the services array, upon clicking it afterwards, the active tag does not get applied to the new entry. It should turn blue and add to the total price but only the hover state works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified you code at method 'addItem' and use computed property total instead  total method,have a look:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
    services: [
      {
      name: 'Item 1',
      price: 200,
      active: true
    },
    {
      name: 'Item 2',
      price: 500,
      active: false
    },
    {
    name: 'Item 3',
      price: 700,
      active: false
    }
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    total () {
      return this.services.reduce((last,item)=>last + parseInt(item.price) * item.active,0)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
    addItem: function() {
      var newItem= {
        name:this.name,
        price:this.price,
        active: true
      };
      this.services.push(newItem);
      this.name="";
      this.price="";
    },
    toggleActive: function(f) {
      f.active = !f.active;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
}

h3 {
  text-align:center;
  padding: 2em 0em;
}

h5 {
  padding: 1.5em 0.5em;;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  width:600px;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

ul {
  list-style:none;
}
li {
  color:black;
  border:1px solid #eeeeee;
  padding:0.5em;
  border-left: 5px solid #2196F3;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}



.active {
  background-color:#2196F3;
  color:white;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.active:hover {
  background-color:#2196F3;
}

li:hover {
  background-color:#82c4f8;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  cursor:pointer;
}

span {
  float:right;
}

#main {
box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0,0,0,0.0), 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.22)
}

.text-center {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.27/vue.min.js"></script>

       <div class="container">
  <div id="main">
<div class="header"><h3>Click the services you wish to have:</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="group-item" v-for="service in services"  v-on:click="toggleActive(service)" v-bind:class="{'active': service.active}">{{service.name}} <span>{{service.price | currency}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    <h5>Total is: {{total | currency}}</h5>
  <input type="text" v-model="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="text" v-model="price" placeholder="price">
  <button v-on:click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain to me the reasoning for this code?  


`return this.services.reduce((last,item)=>last + parseInt(item.price) *     item.active,0)`

Can you explain it to me? I am new to vue.js and want to understand the logic behind this code.

Comment: computed property,you can use is as a property like other property your define in data,it's essentially a function.It's value depends on the return the value of the function.value is reactive, it means that, when this function is dependent on other values change, the function will be recalculated, as you see, when the choice/cancel one, according to the results of the total will automatically change, this is a very useful feature

Comment: about Array.prototype.reduce,see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that you're running into is you're calling an undefined function and not passing a parameter into your `toggleActive` function.

Since `toggleActive` is a Vue method, you'll need to use `this` to reference it correctly and use the function from your Vue instance; once that problem is fixed, you'll need to pass in the item that you're wanting to toggle, because the way that function is written it requires a parameter to update active status.

Here's how you could update your `addItem` function to get it working:

```
addItem: function() {
  var newItem= {
    name:this.name,
    price:this.price,
    active: false,
  };
  this.services.push(newItem);
  this.name="";
  this.price="";
  this.toggleActive(this.services[this.services.length - 1]);
},
```

Also notice that I added the `active` property during item creation so that Vue treats this as a reactive property. Otherwise, your item will be stuck in the active state (after toggling it) and cannot become inactive on click. You could change this to just be `active: true` during creation (and remove the call to make it active completely) if all new items are supposed to be active on creation. I didn't do that, though, as I wanted to show how to fix the call to `toggleActive`.

You can view a forked and updated [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mattjenkins/pen/YvKgdJ) here if you'd like to see the code in a fully working state.